# LatticeReduce (2D) more than two vector

Tags: vector, implementation-details, lattices

I wonder how `LatticeReduce` works when I use more than two vector arguments each one in 2D. I know the Gauss algorithm to reduce two vectors. However, how `LatticeReduce` handles more than two vectors (basis)?

The result for `LatticeReduce[{{1,3}, {3,1}, {4,4}}]` is `{{1, 3}, {-2, -2}}`. The same as `LatticeReduce[{{1,3}, {3,1}}]` because `{{1,3}, {3,1}}` are generators.

Comment: As noted in the linked thread, LLL is the underlying algorithm.

Comment: It works by first computing the Hermite normal form, then using the nonzero rows in a full rank lattice reduction. I should add that this was not really a duplicate of the linked question.